# Open emacs in basic mode as default editor

Tags: terminal-emacs

I want to set emacs as the default editor for crontab

```
me@me:~$ cat .selected_editor 
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs -nw"
```

but find this solution too heavy for some easy task, so I re-configure it as

```
me@me:~$ cat .selected_editor 
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs -Q"
```

emacs was opened but in a GUI mode

How could I open it in terminal in a basic mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply combine the arguments you've already used:

```
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs -Q -nw"
```

Comment: amazing, why emacs -Wnw not working.

Comment: -W is not a valid option. See `man emacs` for a list.

Comment: Or `emacs --help`

Comment: @Alice, if you read somewhere that `-Wnw` would be valid, perhaps you could try to correct that source.